# Cannot get an ID's of an array elements for key in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to the instructions in the React documentation, it is possible to set the `keys` of the elements of the `array` by it's `ID`. 
Actually the question is, where does the react take the ID data according to the instruction (and its does not be an **index** of an elements):

From React doc: *The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys:*

```
const todoItems = todos.map((todo) =>
  <li key={todo.id}>
    {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```

But for some reason it does not work for me:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const map = this.props.list.map(
      (li) => <li key={li.id}>{li}</li> // keys does an attached
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {map} 
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const testRenderer = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent list={testRenderer} />,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: ID here refers to something that you would use to identify each data item.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are passing an array of numbers in `testRenderer`, but your map function expects an `id` in each item of the array. Try this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const map = this.props.list.map(
      (li, index) => <li key={index.toString()}>{li}</li>
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {map} 
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const testRenderer = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent list={testRenderer} />,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Now you use the `testRenderer` item as the `key` value.

Comment: No, its does not be an `index` in ID of an elements according to the React docs

Comment: Max, the `key` can be any unique value. `index` is just an example for a possible `key`.

Comment: In this way you can crash your app in case of reorder of an array elements (on filter page for example)

Comment: Could you explain further on that?

Comment: You can see the official docs: reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are iterating through an array with your the `map()` function and then trying to call an object within the loop.

`li.id` does not exist because `li` is not an object. It is a value within the array you are iterating over.

You can use the array key value like so:

```
const map = this.props.list.map(
  (li, key) => <li key={key}>{li}</li> // where key will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
);
```

Comment: In this way you can crash your app in case of reorder of an array elements (on filter page for example). See the official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

Answer (score 0):

The use of element's `index` in an `array` is not a correct approach for creating `ID's`. In connection with this, we are also given a statement directly by the **React**:

" *As a last resort, you can pass an item’s index in the array as a key. This can work well if the items are never reordered, but reorders will be slow.*

*Reorders can also cause issues with component state when indexes are used as keys. Component instances are updated and reused based on their key. If the key is an index, moving an item changes it. As a result, component state for things like controlled inputs can get mixed up and updated in unexpected ways.* "

You can see more info from the advanced official guide: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

And find there a two examples from why it's so important to non-usage the indexes for keys in the **Keys section**.

So, if we want to do all right, we need to create a `state` update method for incoming `array`, that will make a unique `ID` for each `element` of incoming external `array`. In this way we will have a full countrol about incoming `array` of any length and also we'll never make a wrong sort by `ID's` in case of reorder the element of an `array`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      arrayObj: {
          id: '',
          list: ''
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() { // make new state with 
                         // object besides on incoming array
    let count = 0;
    let arrCount = [];
    let arrs = this.props.list;

    this.props.list.forEach( // make the ID for each element of an array
      (li) => {
        arrCount.push(++count); 
      } 
    );

    this.setState({
      arrayObj: {
          id: arrCount,
          list: arrs
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <MakeList obj={this.state.arrayObj} />
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

class MakeList extends React.Component{ // support component for 
                                    // render current obj state children
  render() {
    let object = this.props.obj;
    let arr = [];

    for (var key in object.list) {
      arr.push(<li key={object.id[key]}>{object.list[key]}</li>)
    }
    return arr;
  }
}

const testRenderer = ['11', '22', '33', '44', '55'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent list={testRenderer} />,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want. Thank you for so great explanation!